# Why do i have a conflict between ORM and mongo fixtures on Symfony 4

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, fixtures

i have a problem which is basically driving me crazy during the last day and a half: I have a Symfony 4 and I use both PostgreSQL and MongoDB. In order to handle the mongodb documents I use the Doctrine MongoDB Bundle

I have my normal entities on /src/Entity folder, and my mongo class on /src/Document folder. So far so good when using the classes with entity and document managers

The problem comes with the fixtures, I have created two folders
- /src/DataFixtures/ORM where most of my fixtures live
- /src/DataFixtures/MongoDB where my new fixture for mongo document lives

my Mongo fixture class:

```
use App\Document\ImportFeedExecution;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture; 
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

/**
 * ExecutionFixtures class
 */
 class ExecutionFixtures extends Fixture
 {
     public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
     {
         $exec = new ImportFeedExecution();
         $exec->setFeedId(1);
         $exec->setStatus(ImportFeedExecution::STATUS_RUNNING);

         $manager->persist($exec);

         $manager->flush($exec);
     }
}
```

The fact is, if i run bin/console doctrine:mongodb:fixtures:load -n it works perfectly, it empties my mongodb database, run this and all good, but if i run bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load -n i get an error now! which is:

```
In MappingException.php line 22:
The class 'App\Document\ImportFeedExecution' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity
```

At the moment, my doctrine and mongo configurations are pretty much defaults. Is there a reason why my mongo fixture is detected as a normal fixture?

Answer (score 0):

my fault :/, I accidentally left a copy of ExecutionFixtures.php into the ORM folder
executing the fixtures load with the --verbose pointed me to my error